# Using `<tactic> in <Hypothesis>` pattern for user defined tactics

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

There are many tactics in the standard library, such as the `simpl_list`, `simpl_map`, etc. which do not have a `in` form. This is awkward, because many a times, I'd like to run `simpl_list` within the context of a hypothesis.

Is there some way to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, `simpl_list` is just `autorewrite with list` so you can do `autorewrite with list in H`. I don't see `simpl_map` in the standard library.

Unfortunately there's no general way to take a tactic and run it in another context (specifically, the `in H`, `in *`, and `in *|-` variants the builtin tactics tend to provide). It's also a fairly manual process to write each of these variants and use `Tactic Notation` to give the same syntax, which is why you don't always see all the variants.